# Get Parent Entity from Spring data Repository

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, spring-data, google-cloud-datastore, spring-cloud

How can I get parent `Entity` object from `SubEntity` object.

`subEntityRepository.findById(id)` and then `getEntity()` return `null` entity object.

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Reference
    private List<SubEntity> subEntity;


    public Building(List<SubEntity> subEntity) {
        this.subEntity = subEntity;
    }

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class SubEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Reference
    private Entity entity;

    //getters and setters
}

public interface EntityRepository extends DatastoreRepository<Entity, Long> {}


public interface SubEntityRepository extends DatastoreRepository<SubEntity, Long>{}
```

P.S. This is Google DataStore DB! No OneToMany, no other JPA annotations is available.

Comment: your subEntityRepo is really DatastoreRepository<Entity, Long> and not DatastoreRepository<SubEntity, Long> ?

Comment: Sorry, mistype, it is  DatastoreRepository<SubEntity, Long>

Comment: maybe "@OneToMany" in your entity class instead of both @Reference

Comment: i am also curious about this `@Reference`annotation! (toplink?) what is your "jpa provider" and why you expect this to work?

Comment: It is spring-cloud google platform, it doesnt support one to many

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entity")
public class Entity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="entity")
    private List<SubEntity> subEntity;

    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name="subEntity")
public class SubEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity")
    private Entity entity;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Google DataStore is NoSQL database, so it doesn't support ManyToOne, OneToMany or JoinColumn annotations.